# Construct the Array from HackerRank

Tags: java, programming-challenge

This is my answer for 
https://www.hackerrank.com/challenges/construct-the-array/problem
(Passes all the test cases)

**Problem**

> Your goal is to find the number of ways to construct an array such
>   that consecutive positions contain different values.
>
> Specifically, we
>   want to construct an array with \$n\$ elements such that each element
>   [contains a value] between \$1\$ and \$k\$, inclusive.
>   We also want the first and last
>   elements of the array to be \$1\$ and \$x\$. Given \$n\$, \$k\$ and \$x\$, find
>   the number of ways to construct such an array.
>
> Since the answer may be
>   large, only find answer modulo \$10^9 + 7\$
>
> **For example**, for \$n=4\$, \$k=3\$ and \$x=2\$ there are \$3\$ ways

**Solution**

```
public class Solution {
    public static final long MOD = 1_000_000_007L;

    public static long countArray(int n, int k, int x) {
        if (n < 3 || k < 2) return 0;
        if (n == 3 && x == 1) {
            return k - 1;
        }
        if (n == 3) {
            return k - 2;
        }
        long countOne = k - 1, countOther = k - 2, temp;
        for (int i = 4; i < n; i++) {
            temp = countOther * (k - 1) % MOD;
            countOther = (countOne % MOD + countOther * (k - 2) % MOD) % MOD;
            countOne = temp;
        }
        if (x == 1) {
            return countOther * (k - 1) % MOD;
        }
        return (countOne % MOD + countOther * (k - 2) % MOD) % MOD;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**"Impossible" check**

Per task description, `k >= 2` and `n >= 3`. But nevertheless you're performing this "impossible" check:

```
if (n < 3 || k < 2) return 0;
```

**Redundant check**

I don't understand why you're checking cases `n == 3` separately. You could remove these `2` checks and have this case handled in your `for` loop quite easily as below (please note that the values of `i`, `countOne` and `countOther` have changed):

```
long countOne = 0, countOther = 1, temp;
for (int i = 3; i < n; i++) {
    temp = countOther * (k - 1) % MOD;
    countOther = (countOne % MOD + countOther * (k - 2) % MOD) % MOD;
    countOne = temp;
}
```

**Variable naming**

`countOne` or `countOther` are not a good way to call your variables - their names don't convey their purpose. I'll leave it up to you to come up with better names.

**Excessive modulo operation**

You don't have to perform a modulo operation more times than is needed. Given you task constraints, your can perform a modulo operation twice per iteration as below:

```
temp = countOther * (k - 1) % MOD;
countOther = (countOne + countOther * (k - 2)) % MOD;
countOne = temp;
```

**Reduce scope of `temp`**

As @Barmar correctly pointed out, your `temp` variable should be local to the `for` loop. It's not needed anywhere out of it.

**Simplify return statements**

You don't have to calculate `countOne` or `countOther` once you leave the `for` loop. You can do it all there, just fix your loop condition from `i < n` to `i <= n` and swap `countOne` with `countOther` in your `return` statements.

```
for (int i = 3; i <= n; i++) {
    long temp = countOther * (k - 1) % MOD;
    countOther = (countOne + countOther * (k - 2)) % MOD;
    countOne = temp;
}

if (x == 1) {
    return countOne;
}

return countOther;
```

**Final Code**

```
public static long countArray(int n, int k, int x) {

    long countOne = 0, countOther = 1;
    for (int i = 3; i <= n; i++) {
        long temp = countOther * (k - 1) % MOD;
        countOther = (countOne + countOther * (k - 2)) % MOD;
        countOne = temp;
    }


    return x == 1 ? countOne : countOther;
}
```

Comment: I chose this answer becuase I like how you simplified my code. Thanks :)

Answer (score 6):

I suggest that you extract the similar evaluations in methods.

```java
    private static long countFirst(int k, long countOther, int i) {
        return countOther * (k - i) % MOD;
    }

    private static long countNext(int k, long countOne, long countOther) {
        return (countOne % MOD + countFirst(k, countOther, 2)) % MOD;
    }
```

````java
//[...]
   long countOne = k - 1;
   long countOther = k - 2;
   long temp;

   for (int i = 4; i < n; i++) {
      temp = countFirst(k, countOther, 1);
      countOther = countNext(k, countOne, countOther);
      countOne = temp;
   }

   if (x == 1) {
      return countFirst(k, countOther, 1);
   }

   return countNext(k, countOne, countOther);
//[...]
```
````

Answer (score 3):

You are checking conditions multiple times, increasing the complexity of the code.  For example:

```
    if (n == 3 && x == 1) {
        return k - 1;
    }
    if (n == 3) {
        return k - 2;
    }
```

checks `n == 3` twice.  A nested `if` statement would be simpler & clearer:

```
    if (n == 3) {
        if (x == 1) {
            return k - 1;
        } else {
            return k - 2;
        }
    }
```

---

Despite passing all the tests, this code may give the wrong result if `n = 3` and `k > MOD`, unless the problem imposed a limit on `k` not reflected in the above problem description.

Comment: You are correct k isn't larger than MOD :)